# Studying the family of curves $\beta(s,r) = \alpha(s) + r\,{\bf N}(s)$

Tags: differential-geometry, curves, frenet-frame

I'm reviewing some stuff on plane curves, just because, and I would like to confirm some things. The whole exercise is:

> Let $\alpha(s) = (x(s),y(s))$ be a unit-speed parametrized curve, ${\bf N}(s)$ its normal vector and $\kappa(s)$ its curvature. Consider the family of curves $\beta(s,r) = \alpha(s) +r\,{\bf N}(s)$, $-\epsilon \leq r \leq \epsilon$. Check that $\beta(s,r_0)$ and $\beta(s_0, r)$ are regular curves for $\epsilon > 0$ small enough, check that they're orthogonal and that the curvature $\overline{\kappa}$ of $\beta(s,r_0)$ is $\frac{\kappa}{1+r_0\kappa}$.

A direct computation gives: $$\left\|\frac{\partial \beta}{\partial s}(s,r_0)\right\| = |1-r_0\kappa(s)|, \quad \left\|\frac{\partial \beta}{\partial r}(s_0, r)\right\| = 1,$$ so that $\beta(s_0, r)$ is always regular. My first problem is with the first curve. If $|\kappa(s)|$ attained a maximum, say, $|\kappa^\ast|$, then I can take $0 < \epsilon < 1/|\kappa^\ast|$ and from this $|1-r_0\kappa(s)| > 0$ for all $s$.

> The exercise was written sloppily and I should assume that $\alpha$ is defined in a closed interval, so that I can obtain this maximum $|\kappa^\ast|$? Or there's a trick around it?

The second part is too easy, no problems.

For the final part, I think that the formula given is wrong. Because $$\frac{\partial \beta}{\partial s}(s,r_0) = (1-r_0\kappa(s))\,{\bf T}(s), \quad \frac{\partial^2\beta}{\partial s^2}(s,r_0)= -r_0\kappa'(s)\,{\bf T}(s) + (1-r_0\kappa(s))\kappa(s)\,{\bf N}(s)$$will give: $$\det\left(\frac{\partial \beta}{\partial s}(s,r_0),\frac{\partial^2\beta}{\partial s^2}(s,r_0)\right) = (1-r_0\kappa(s))^2\kappa(s)$$ and so: $$\overline{\kappa}(s) = \frac{\kappa(s)}{|1-r_0\kappa(s)|}.$$

> Did I miss anything? In [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1124504/a-valuable-question-about-differential-geometry-the-curve-betas-alphas-rn), for example, they take $\alpha (s)- r\,{\bf N}(s)$ in the beginning, which is coherent with my work above. But I think I have too many absolute values there, too. Is there a way to get rid of them?

Comment: If the problem doesn't say anything about the domain of $s$, how can you choose it such that $\kappa(s) \ne \frac 1 {r_0}$?

Comment: Yeah, that's the point. But if $\kappa$ is bounded I can work around it and find $\epsilon > 0$ such that it'll work for all $-\epsilon \leq r \leq \epsilon$. I guess there are some hypothesis missing..

Comment: @IvoTerek can you explain how you checked that the curves are orthogonal? I'm trying to do the same exercise but I'm having trouble with  the orthogonality proof and finding the curvature.

Answer (score 0):

Since your curve is parametrized by the arc length the following relations hold: ${\bf N}'(s)= -k(s) {\bf T}(s)$ and $\alpha'(s)={\bf T}(s)$. So for your final part the relation $\frac{\partial \beta}{\partial s}(s,r_0) = (1-r_0\kappa(s))\,{\bf T}(s)$ is correct as well as the second derivative of $\beta$. We can then conclude that the curvature  of $\beta(s)$ is $\overline{\kappa}(s) = \frac{\kappa(s)}{1-r_0\kappa(s)}$. The curvature can effectively be computed by using the cross product  $\beta'(s) \times  \beta''(s)$ and by taking the component in the $z$ direction. Since ${\bf T}(s)$ is a unit vector its module is $1$. When reversing the sign in your original curve, i.e. when considering a parallel curve at a distance $r$ as $\beta(s)=\alpha (s)- r\,{\bf N}(s)$, the corresponding geodesic curvature can be obtained from the previous one by replacing $r$ by $-r$.
Concerning the regularity condition of $\beta(s)$, this is satisfied if $\frac{1}{r}$ is not between the extremal values of the geodesic curvature.
This means that if we define $k_{min}=\min \{\overline {k(s)} \}$ and $k_{max}=\max \{ \overline{k(s)} \}$ then $\beta(s)$ is regular if and only if $\frac 1 r \not \in [ k_{min},k_{max} ]$.

Comment: How can I show the two curves are orthogonal? Taking the dot product $\beta'(s, r_0)\cdot \beta'(s_0, r) = \alpha'(s)n(s_0)(1-r_0k(s))$ didn't work for me, as I can't see how that equals $0$.